# Find hyperlink in the table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table with some data and last column has a hyperlink for all the rows in the table. I need to open a dialog on click of the hyperlink.

```
<table id="tableId">
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td><a href="">edit</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

$("#tableId tr a[href]").on("click", function() {
   console.log("Hello World");
   $("<div></div>).dialog({});
});
```

My console doesn't show hello world probably some error in the jquery code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing Quote missing `"<div></div>"`

```
 $("<div></div>").dialog({});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Mh5hq/)**

It is better to give hash `#` in href like this,

```
<a href="#">edit</a>
```

You code would be

```
$("#tableId tr a[href]").on("click", function() {
   console.log("Hello World");
   $("<div></div>).dialog({});
   return false; 
});
```

Comment: I added # in href but doesn't seem to recognize the click

Comment: I am unable to to click on Live Demo.

Comment: I used your code in example, is it dialog not being shown? do you get the alert?

Comment: I didn't get the alert too. I had commented the dialog code and was trying to find if the click is recognized or not but the click is not recognized.

Comment: Is there any other way to access table cells that has hyperlink or check if any row contains "edit"  text then click on it triggers the events